# Magento custm table data updating issue

Tags: magento

I have a custom table which has primary key with **varchar** data type. I need to update some records accordingly. I used below code to load the specific row;

```
$model = Mage::getModel('test/one')->load($Sku,'CODE');
```

**CODE** is the primary key field value. *All the table field names are in capital letters.*

When i am trying edit by using below code, i am getting a Duplicate entry error.

```
$model->setData('DESC','test description');
model->save();
```

I think it is trying to insert a new record instead of updating. But why that is happening. Can anyone please help me.

Thank You so much.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this method

```
$model = Mage::getModel('test/one')->load($Sku,'CODE');
$data = array("position"=> "DESC", "content"=> "test description");
$model = model->addData($data);
$model->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of why is trying to insert a new row is that the call to `load()` is returning `null` and therefore not an existing row from your table. 
Try adding a condition either after `load()` or before `save()`.

```
$model = Mage::getModel('test/one')->load($Sku,'CODE');
     if(!this->getId()){
        echo "no existing row found";
     }
```

beyond that you might want to debug to find out why `load()` is returning `null`